# Can Artifactory talk to a Swift object store without S3?

Tags: artifactory

We are planning to use Artifactory to front end an existing binary object store.  That object store currently only supports swift.  They plan to support S3 in the next year, but I would like to begin prototyping with the two pieces now.  Can I point Artifactory at an object store that only supports Swift?  Or is only "Swift via S3" supported as seen here (https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/S3+Object+Storage)?

Thanks,
Heath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the only option for connecting Artifactory to Swift will be to use S3 protocol.

Comment: Thank you.   That's what I was afraid of.